# ruby selenium element.click has different output with different environment

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'    
caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.firefox    
caps['acceptInsecureCerts'] = true    
@driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:firefox, desired_capabilities: caps)    
@driver.navigate.to "https://s1.demo.opensourcecms.com/s/44"    
el=@driver.find_element(:xpath,"//span[contains(text(),'Remove Frame')]").click    
p el
```

Output with following Setup

> 2.6.0 :006 > @driver.find_element(:xpath,"//span[contains(text(),'Remove Frame')]").click
>    => nil

Environment

1. Mozilla Firefox 60.5.0
2. ruby 2.6.0p0 (2018-12-25 revision 66547)[x86_64-linux]
3. selenium-webdriver-3.141.0

   Output with the following Setup

> 2.1.2 :006 > @driver.find_element(:xpath,"//span[contains(text(),'Remove Frame')]").click
>    => "ok"

Environment

1. Mozilla Firefox 52.2.0
2. ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-linux]
3. selenium-webdriver-2.53.4

Comment: Why two different environment has different output one is nill and other is ok when we click?

Answer (score 0):

[click method](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/selenium-webdriver/0.0.28/Selenium/WebDriver/Element#click-instance_method) doesn't return an explicit value, so it returns `nil` by Ruby default.

Comment: Previously it was returned "ok" with ruby version ruby 2.1.2p95, Firefox  52.2.0 and selenium-webdriver-2.53.4

Comment: @jaswantgupta `click` has never returned anything, you must have looked at something else.